# What is the difference between "supplant" , "supersede", and "replace"?

Tags: synonyms

The words *supplant*, *supersede*, and *replace* share similar meaning. What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Each of the three terms employed a different word picture to arrive at the same point of meaning.

*[Supplant](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=supplant&allowed_in_frame=0)* reached the meaning *[take the place of](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/supplant)* by extension from ***under foot***, *trip up* and *defeat*:

> early 14c., "to trip up, overthrow, defeat, dispossess,"
>   from Old
>   French suplanter, sosplanter "to trip up, overthrow, drive out,
>   usurp,"
>   or directly from Latin supplantare "trip up, overthrow," from
>   sub "under" (see *[sub](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sub-&allowed_in_frame=0)*-) + planta "sole of the foot" (see *[plant](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=plant&allowed_in_frame=0)* (n.)).
>   Meaning "replace one thing with another" first recorded 1670s.

*[Supersede](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=supersede&allowed_in_frame=0)* reached the meaning *[take the place of](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/supersede)* by extension from ***sit on top of*** and *defer*:

> mid-15c., Scottish, "postpone, defer,"
>   from Middle French superceder
>   "desist, delay, defer,"
>   from Latin supersedere literally "sit on top
>   of;" also, with ablative, "stay clear of, abstain from, forbear,
>   refrain from,"
>   from super "above" (see *[super](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=super-&allowed_in_frame=0)*-) + sedere "to sit" (see
>   *[sedentary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sedentary&allowed_in_frame=0)*).
>   Meaning "displace, replace" first recorded 1640s.

*[Replace](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=replace&allowed_in_frame=0)* reached the meaning of *[take the place of](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/replace)* from ***place again***:

> 1590s, "to restore to a previous place or position,"
>   from *[re](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=re-&allowed_in_frame=0)*- "back,
>   again" + *[place](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=place&allowed_in_frame=0)* (v.).
>   Meaning "to take the place of" is recorded from
>   1753;
>   that of "to fill the place of (with something else)" is from
>   1765.

Although modern native speakers of English may not consciously form these word pictures when speaking and writing these words, the residual connotations are still implied by our intuitive understanding of the prefixes and roots involved. Employing these subtle connotations effectively enhances our enjoyment of the communication process. The semantic and syntactical interaction with other words in the context may alter the focus of each word, but:

> In *supplant*, the focus starts at *bringing down*.
>
> In *supersede*, the focus starts at *rising above*.
>
> In *replace*, the focus starts at *lateral substitution*.

Answer (score 5):

[Supplant](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/supplant) to me implies a direct contest, where the supplanting party is coming from obscurity or lower status to take the more prominent position of the supplanted one.

[Supersede](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/supersede) implies some form of outside measurement of qualities/parameters and a decision being reached based on comparing these metrics. One can supplant a king by luck, guile or brute force, but he isn't superseded until the subsequent ruler proves themselves more capable.

[Replace](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/replace) makes no explicit statement of superiority or any kind of comparison or contest, it is merely an observed fact - one thing is replaced by another.